# Инициализация массива с помощью конструктора Java

Tags: java, конструктор

Необходимо реализовать пузырьковую сортировку для массива. При этом массив инициализируется с помощью:

1. пустого конструктора, при вызове которого генерируется массив с random значениями
2. конструктора, который на вход принимает длину и массив

Метод для генерации рэндом массива:

```
 public static int[] arrayCreator() {
    int arr[] = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 5));
    }
    return arr;
} 


public void arrayPrint(int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Пузырьковая сортировка:

```
public void bubbleSort(int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                int t = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс и конструтор:

```
public class Starter {

    private static int arr[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = {1, 9, 6, -2, 12};
        Starter starter = new Starter();
        starter.arrayPrint(arr);
        starter.bubbleSort(arr);
        System.out.println("Array after sorting: ");
        starter.arrayPrint(arr);    
    }

    Starter() {
        int arr[] = arrayCreator();
    }

    Starter(int length, int array[]) {
        int arr[] = array;
    }
```

При создании обьекта `starter` конструктор не вызывается, массив не инициализуется. Дальше `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В конструкторах класса вы инициализируете локальные массивы вместо массива - члена класса.

```
Starter() {
    int arr[] = arrayCreator();
    ^^^^^^^^^
}

Starter(int length, int array[]) {
    int arr[] = array;
    ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Вам надо инициализировать член класса, а не объявлять в конструкторах локальные массивы.

Также это плохая идея делать массив статическим членом класса. Каждый объект класса должен иметь свой член класса в виде массива.

Кроме того непонятно, почему вы используете магическое число `5` в функции генерации массива со случайными значениями

```
 public static int[] arrayCreator() {
            int arr[] = new int[5];
                        ^^^^^^^^^^
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 5));
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

Было бы более логично, если бы в эту функцию передавался аргумент, который указывал бы, какова должна быть размерность массива. Например,

```
 public static int[] arrayCreator( int n ) {
            int arr[] = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 5));
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

Также если эти функции создания массивов используются только в конструкторах, то лучше объявить их с классом доступа `private`. Дополнительно можно написать еще одну `public` функцию типа `reset`, которая устанавливает новые случайные значения для элементов массива.

Также совершенно не ясно, почему не статическая функция член класса `arrayPrint`  имеет параметр тогда, как она должна распечатывать массив своего объекта

```
public void arrayPrint(int arr[]) {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

лучше было бы определить ее как

```
public void arrayPrint() {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^   
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

и соответственно вызывать без аргумента.

Обратите внимание, что объявленный в функции `main` массив

```
int array[] = {1, 9, 6, -2, 12};
```

нигде не используется.

Что касается вашей функции пузырьковой сортировки, то она будет выполнять циклы и проход по всему массиву, даже если массив уже отсортирован. Вы можете посмотреть ответ на [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453330/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E/453342#453342), чтобы сделать сортировку более эффективной. Хотя в том вопросе требуется отсортировать массив по убыванию, тем не мене это только сказывается на том, какой оператор логического отношения будет использовать. А в целом показан алгоритм сортировки, уменьшающий число проходов по массиву.

Answer (score 3):

Конструктор вызывается, но в нём вы инициализируете локальную переменную.

```
int arr[] = arrayCreator();
```

запоминает созданный массив в локальной переменной, которая исчезает после того, как конструктор отработал.

Пишите так:

```
arr = arrayCreator();
```

Да, и `arr` не стоит объявлять как `static`, даже ваш класс создаётся всего лишь один раз. Всё же это данные, относящиеся к экземпляру класса.